# ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE' error on using svg2png npm library

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I am trying to use the svg2png library to convert the svg files to png files.
The code chunk I'm using is:

```
const fs = require("pn/fs"); // https://www.npmjs.com/package/pn
const svg2png = require("svg2png");

function main(){
    var myArgs = process.argv.slice(2);
    console.log('myArgs: ', myArgs);
    if(myArgs.length==0){
        console.log("Failed");
        return
    }
    fs.readFile(myArgs[0])
        .then((x) => svg2png(x,{ width: 800, height: 600 }))
        .then(buffer => fs.writeFile(myArgs[0].replace("svg","png"), buffer))
        .catch(e => console.error(e));
}
main();
```

on running the code by using command

```
node convert_svg2png.js '/users/sakshambhalla/Downloads/logos/albertvillejobs/img/logo.svg'
```

I am getting the following error:

```
myArgs:  [ '/users/sakshambhalla/Downloads/logos/albertvillejobs/img/logo.svg' ]
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "file" argument must be of type string. Received type object
    at validateString (internal/validators.js:118:11)
    at normalizeSpawnArguments (child_process.js:404:3)
    at spawn (child_process.js:544:13)
    at Object.execFile (child_process.js:230:17)
    at Object.execFile (/Users/sakshambhalla/Downloads/convert/node_modules/pn/_promisify.js:50:27)
    at /Users/sakshambhalla/Downloads/convert/node_modules/svg2png/lib/svg2png.js:13:33 {
  code: 'ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE'
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: maybe this tool depends on a command line too, which you don't have installed.

Comment: did you try reading the code for the svg2png library? is it doing spawn?